# How to properly duplicate a Laravel project in the same computer?

Tags: laravel

So I want to create a Laravel project, and 70% of the content will be the same as the project I worked before, so I plan to copy/duplicate an old project and start from there. How do I do it? I tried copying it and change the database, but whenever I tried to 'serve' it, it just serve the old project so I must be doing something wrong.

Comment: How do you define the old project is being served? if you have two projects /project1 /project2 and you cd into project2 and serve it you can only run these files.

Comment: @mrhn I run 'php artisan serve' on project2 but when I go to the development server, it serve the project 1.

Comment: make sure to clear the cache data, ``php artisan cache:clear``